# Google Chrome : hide "drag to share"

Tags: google-chrome

The "Drag to share" message popping in the middle of images or media content is quite annoying... is there a way to hide it?

Comment: What extensions do you have installed? This is message from an extension, Chrome doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try disabling your Meebo extension.

I also [found](http://forums.mangafox.com/threads/270827-drag-to-share):

> If you're using Firefox with Ad Block plus do this:
>
> Tools > AdBlockPlus Preferences
>
> Then click Add Filter at the bottom and type: meebo.com#div(id$=-MediaBar)
> It should work if not add another filter and type: ##m[class*="meebo"]
>
> I think it would also work for Chrome.

Comment: where is that? I don't have that extension listed in the 'extensions' setup page

Comment: Are there any extensions installed?

Comment: stupid Meebo...